# yii2 join - не выводятся столбцы для которых нет соответсвия

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Здравствуйте, есть такой код

```
$model = Agency::find()->select([ '{{agency}}.agency_name','SUM({{billing}}.amount) AS sumAmount',
    '{{agency_network}}.agency_network_name AS net_name'
             ])->innerJoinWith(['agencyNetwork', 'billings'], false)
               ->where(['between', 'date', $date->startDate, $date->endDate])
               ->groupBy('{{agency}}.agency_id')
               ->all();

      print_r($model);
```

здесь `join` объединяет таблицы `agency` и `billing`, связь `agency` один к `biling` многим, и считаем сумму из поля `amount` для каждого ключа `agency`. Все работает хорошо, но если нет соответствия ключей, т.е. если `id` в `agency` отсутствует в `agency_id` в `biling`, то поля из `agency` не записываются в объект, а нужно что бы если не было соответствия вывести поля `agency` и поставить 0 в `SUM`.

Answer (score 2):

Это потому что вы используете `INNER JOIN` -- он так и работает, отбрасывает все строки для которых нет соответсвия в условии `ON`.

Попробуйте заменить

```
->innerJoinWith(['agencyNetwork', 'billings'], false)
```

на

```
->joinWith(['agencyNetwork', 'billings'], false, 'LEFT OUTER JOIN')
```

Answer (score 0):

Выше приведенный пример верный но не совсем, что бы правильно сработал left join нельзя использовать оператор WHERE вместо этого нужно писать условие после ON
    return Agency::find()->select([
                                    '{{agency}}.agency_name',
                                    'COALESCE(SUM({{billing}}.amount), 0) AS sumAmount',
                                    '{{agency_network}}.agency_network_name AS net_name'
                                ])
                                ->joinWith([ 
                                        'agencyNetwork',
                                        'billings' => function($query) use($startDate, $endDate)
                                        {
                                            $query->onCondition("`date` BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'");
                                        }
                                ], false)
                                //->where(['between', 'date', $date->startDate, $date->endDate])
                                ->groupBy('{{agency}}.agency_id')
                                ->all();